# how to use font awesome icons online

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.03.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not working
How can I use symbols from font awesome in my website online

Comment: you can't access to cdn http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.03.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the console, you'll see that you can't access this href link. Try this way:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/29ecae9da7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can find the icons: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

Answer (score 0):

just replace the link tag with this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and with this tag as icon tag

```
<i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```